# Как сделать условие ,что если количество True в группе меньше или равно 3м-делать условие?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

Не могу понять как дополнить код.

К условию, которое находится в `for i, data in group.iterrows():` мне надо добавить, что если таких значений, удовлетворяющих условию

```
if (data['users_comm_week']==0)&
    (data['users_comm_month']!=0)&
    (~pd.isnull(data['IMEI']))&
    (data['status']<100)&
    (data['car_id']!=-1)&
    (~pd.isnull(data['cars_list'])):
```

меньше или равно 3х в группе, то делать это - полный текст кода ниже:

```
import numpy as np
car = []
car_id_head=[]
car_id_tail=[]
cars_list=[]
imei = []
rec_dt=[]
line=[]
ts_last_check=[]
users_comm_day=[]
users_comm_month=[]
users_comm_week=[]
dev_sn=[]
cars_list2=[]

for name, group in groupby_regiment:
    for i, data in group.iterrows():
        if (data['users_comm_month']==0) & (~pd.isnull(data['IMEI'])) & (data['status']<100)& (data['car_id']!=-1)&(~pd.isnull(data['cars_list'])):
            rec_dt.append(data['rec_dt'])
            car.append(data['car_id'])
            cars_list.append(data['cars_list'])
            imei.append(data['IMEI'])
            line.append(data['line_id_x'])
            ts_last_check.append(data['ts_last_check'])
            users_comm_day.append(data['users_comm_day'])
            users_comm_month.append(data['users_comm_month'])
            users_comm_week.append(data['users_comm_week'])
            dev_sn.append(data['dev_sn'])
            car_id_head.append(data['car_id_head'])
            car_id_tail.append(data['car_id_tail'])
            cars_list2.append(data['cars_list2'])
```

Как это лучше сделать?
Входной датафрейм:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Выходной датафрейм:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы можете добавить небольшой пример входных данных (до ~10 строк) в виде текста/Python code/CSV и того что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: http://qaru.site/questions/62951/counting-the-number-of-true-booleans-in-a-python-list

Comment: @splash58, похоже здесь речь идет о Pandas DataFrame - в Pandas есть гораздо более эффективные способы сделать это. ;-) Но пока нет входных и выходных примеров данных в вопросе трудно дать однозначный ответ. В 99% случаев такие вещи в Pandas решаются без использования циклов и это работает на порядки быстрее

Comment: Можете преобразовать false в нолик, а true в единичку? Преобразуйте все и сложите. Если сумма меньше 3, то выполняете условие.

Comment: @IgorLavrynenko Не стоило откланять правку от Twiss, можно было просто улучшить.

Comment: @Kromster вот ровно это по ссылке, которую я привел

Comment: @MaxU  добавил скриншоты

Comment: ```sum(map(bool,[data['users_comm_month']==0 & (~pd.isnull(data['IMEI'])) & (data['status']<100)&(data['car_id']!=-1)&(~pd.isnull(data['cars_list']))]))<=3``` это неверно (

Comment: @AndrewKonstantinov, для того чтобы протестировать решение  нужен, как минимум, входной DataFrame в виде текста/Python code/CSV (я не просто так написал это в комментарии)...

Comment: Для примера можно значительно упростить DataFrame...

Comment: @MaxU https://yadi.sk/d/WPKWaank3RWFpq вот sample датафрейма

Comment: @MaxU могу на почту если что скинуть

Comment: @AndrewKonstantinov, честно говоря лень во всем вашем коде разбираться. Попробуйте привести простой искуссттвенный пример с 5-7 строками и 3-5 столбцами и то что вы ожидаете из него получить... Все равно данный вопрос в таком виде никому в будущем не пригодится, а если сделать более понятный пример данных, то может кому-нибудь и пригодится...